# Оптимизация сравнения двух перечислений наполненных одинаковыми объектами, но с разной структурой и данными C#

Tags: c#, оптимизация, ienumerable

**Всем доброго времени суток!**

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: имеются два перечисления IEnum1, IEnum2. В одном находятся объекты Type1, а в другом Type2. У данных объектов имеются по сути одинаковые поля, но с разными наименованиями. Например, у одного объекта есть поле Number, а у другого есть поле Property, которое в свою очередь содержит поле Value и оно хранит в себе тот самый Number из первого объекта. Связанные объекты между двумя перечислениями можно найти с помощью одного общего поля Date. Поле Date одного из объектов в IEnum1 = полю Date одного из объектов в IEnum2 (поле Date является уникальным внутри одного перечисления). Перечисления не равны! Первое перечисление является основным (оно может быть больше второго или равно, но никогда не меньше!). Сама задача состоит в следующем: нужно создать результирующие перечисление в которое попадут только те элементы из первого перечисления, которые изменились по отношению ко второму и разумеется те элементы, которых совсем нет во втором.

Единственное, что лично мне приходит в голову - это два цикла: сначала по одному перечислению, а внутри по второму и на каждом шаге, проверять по совпадению Date и если совпало, то сравнивать, был ли обновлен объект, и сохранять его, также тут будет понятно, что если таких совпадений не было, то значит это новый объект (тоже сохраняем). Несмотря на такую большую сложность алгоритма, я бы закрыл  глаза на это, если бы не тот факт, что оба массива являются очень большими, а вызов данной будущей функции частой.

Буду рад любой помощи в оптимизации данного процесса!

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var IEnum1 = StubGetKPG();
    var IEnum2 = StubGetExternalModel();

    var result = ComparerIEnums(IEnum1, IEnum2);
            
    foreach(var k in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(k);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static IEnumerable<KPG> StubGetKPG()
{
    return new KPG[]
    {
        // Ситуация, когда объекта нет в External (забираем)
        new KPG()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Date = new DateTime(2022, 01, 01),
            Cost = 12,
            Number = "Первая KPG",
            Comment = "Комментарий 1"
        },
        // Ситуация, когда все поля совпадают (отсеиваем)
        new KPG()
        {
            ID = 2,
            Date = new DateTime(2022, 01, 02),
            Cost = 15,
            Number = "Вторая KPG",
            Comment = "Комментарий 2"
        },
        // Ситуация, когда поля изменились (забираем)
        new KPG()
        {
            ID = 3,
            Date = new DateTime(2022, 01, 03),
            Cost = 18,
            Number = "3 KPG",
            Comment = "Комментарий"
        },
        new KPG()
        {
            ID = 4,
            Date = new DateTime(2022, 01, 04),
            Cost = 10,
            Number = "4",
            Comment = "Комментарий"
        },
        // Ситуация, когда повяилось новое поле (забираем)
        new KPG()
        {
            ID = 5,
            Date = new DateTime(2022, 01, 05),
            Cost = 1,
            Number = "5"
        },
    };
}

private static IEnumerable<ExternalDB> StubGetExternalModel()
{
    return new ExternalDB[]
    {
        // Ситуация, когда объекта нет в External (забираем)

        // Ситуация, когда все поля совпадают (отсеиваем)
        new ExternalDB()
        {
            ID = 4,
            DateTime = new DateTime(2022, 01, 02),
            Value = 15,
            Properties = new Property[] {new Property() { name = "Станция", value = "Вторая KPG" } }
        },
        // Ситуация, когда поля изменились (забираем)
        new ExternalDB() // Изменилост поле Value (Cost)
        {
            ID = 8,
            DateTime = new DateTime(2022, 01, 03),
            Value = 14,
            Properties = new Property[] {new Property() { name = "Станция", value = "3 KPG" } }
        },
        new ExternalDB() // Изменилось одно из свойств
        {
            ID = 74,
            DateTime = new DateTime(2022, 01, 04),
            Value = 10,
            Properties = new Property[] {new Property() { name = "Станция", value = "74" } }
        },
        // Ситуация, когда повяилось новое поле (забираем)
        new ExternalDB() // Появилось свойство Number
        {
            ID = 75,
            DateTime = new DateTime(2022, 01, 05),
            Value = 1
        }
    };
}

// Проверяются на совпадение только нужные поля!
private static IEnumerable<ExternalDB> ComparerIEnums(IEnumerable<KPG> kpgEnum, IEnumerable<ExternalDB> externalEnum)
{
    var result = new List<ExternalDB>();
            
// TODO: Это тот момент, который хочется оптимизировать
    foreach(var kpg in kpgEnum)
    {
        var check = false;
        foreach (var external in externalEnum)
        {
            if (kpg.Date == external.DateTime)
            {
                check = ComparerObjects(kpg, external);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!check)
        {
            result.Add(ExternalFromKPG(kpg));
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static bool ComparerObjects(KPG kpg, ExternalDB external)
{
    // Тут проверяем объекты
    return kpg.Cost == external.Value
        && kpg.Number == external.Properties?.Where(x => x.name == "Станция").Select(x => x.value).FirstOrDefault();
}

private static ExternalDB ExternalFromKPG(KPG kpg)
{
    var properties = new List<Property>();

    if (kpg.Number != null)
    {
        properties.Add(new Property() { name = "Станция", value = kpg.Number });
    }

    return new ExternalDB()
    {
        DateTime = kpg.Date,
        Value = kpg.Cost,
        Properties = properties.ToArray()
    };
}
```

```cs
public sealed class KPG
{
    // 1 пример поля, которое не попадает в сравнение объектов
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int Cost { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    // 2 пример поля, которое не попадает в сравнение объектов
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ExternalDB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
        
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Property[] Properties { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"ID: {ID}, Date: {DateTime}, Значение: {Value}, Свойства: {string.Join(", ", Properties.Select(x => $"{x.name} {x.value}"))}";
    }
}

public sealed class Property
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Результат выполнения данного кода расписан в функции StubGetKPG
Там в комментариях написано, что мы должны взять, а что пропустить и по какой причине

Comment: Кажется вам нужен кастомный EqualityComparer, и можно использовать обычный Union https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-union-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))

Comment: Зачем тратить слова на описание кода, покажите сам код.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к tym32167. Покажите код, чтобы не гадать на кофейной гуще

Comment: Какой должен быть результат для приведенного примера?